# Modifing tkinter same canvas from multiple thread with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to make et Game of life with tkinter. The matrix of the game is a canvas which every cell is a square (white = dead and green = alive).

I wanted to do some multithreading to avoid a too long process time when the matrix is big. But when I'm trying to modify the square color from the threads the window in not responding and I can't solve this problem. I tried a lot of things like putting a common lock in every thread when they are modifying the canvas but it's not working either.
Does someone have ideas to solve this problem or even why this appends?
Thanks by advance

Here's my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import random
from functools import partial


class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        x_coord = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - 600
        y_coord = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 390)
        self.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(1200, 750, x_coord, y_coord))
        """Graphique elements"""
        # Labels
        self.labelcountgen = tk.Label(self, text="Generation 0", font=("Arial", 9))
        self.labelcountgen.grid(row=0, column=1)
        """Graphique data"""
        self.graphiquematrice = tk.Canvas(self, height=740, width=1000, bg='white')
        self.windimention = [1200, 750]
        self.generation = 100
        """Matrice"""
        self.matrice = []
        self.firstquarter = []
        self.secondquarter = []
        self.thirdquarter = []
        self.fourthquarter = []
        self.newmatrice = []
        self.cellids = []
        self.dimention = [70, 100]
        self.density = 15
        self.scale = 10
        self.initmatrice()
        self.launchtime()

    """Init Methodes"""
    def initmatrice(self):
        """
        initialisation du premier etat de la matrice
        """
        self.dimention = [80, 100]
        self.matrice = []
        self.cellids = []
        self.graphiquematrice.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=10)
        for line in range(self.dimention[0]):
            self.matrice.append([])
            self.cellids.append([])
            for col in range(self.dimention[1]):
                chance = random.randrange(1, 100, 1)
                if chance <= self.density:
                    self.matrice[line].append(1)
                    self.cellids[line].append(self.graphiquematrice.create_rectangle(col*self.scale, line*self.scale, (col+1)*self.scale, (line+1)*self.scale, outline='black', fill='green'))
                else:
                    self.matrice[line].append(0)
                    self.cellids[line].append(self.graphiquematrice.create_rectangle(col*self.scale, line*self.scale, (col+1)*self.scale, (line+1)*self.scale, outline='black', fill='white'))
                self.graphiquematrice.tag_bind(self.cellids[line][col], '<Button-1>', partial(self.changestateonclick, self.cellids[line][col]))
    """Calcul Next generation"""
    def launchtime(self):
        for i in range(self.generation):
            self.labelcountgen.config(text="Generation " + str(i + 1))
            self.evolve()
            self.update()

    def getneighboor(self, coord):
        neighboor = []
        for i in range(3):
            lineindex = coord[0] + i - 1
            if lineindex == -1:
                lineindex = self.dimention[0] - 1
            elif lineindex == self.dimention[0]:
                lineindex = 0
            for j in range(3):
                colindex = coord[1] + j - 1
                if colindex == -1:
                    colindex = self.dimention[1] - 1
                elif colindex == self.dimention[1]:
                    colindex = 0
                if lineindex != coord[0] or colindex != coord[1]:
                    neighboor.append(self.matrice[lineindex][colindex])
        return neighboor

    def nextcellstate(self, coord):
        state = self.matrice[coord[0]][coord[1]]
        neighboor = self.getneighboor(coord)
        alive = 0
        dead = 0
        for one in neighboor:
            if one == 0:
                dead += 1
            else:
                alive += 1
        if alive == 3:
            return 1
        elif alive == 2:
            return state
        else:
            return 0

    def nextfirstquarterstate(self, quarter, lock):
        self.firstquarter = []
        start = 0
        for line in range(quarter):
            self.firstquarter.append([])
            for col in range(self.dimention[1]):
                self.firstquarter[line].append(self.nextcellstate([line, col]))
                with lock:
                    if self.firstquarter[line][col] == 0:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line][col], fill='white')
                    else:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line][col], fill='green')

    def nextsecondquarterstate(self, quarter, lock):
        self.secondquarter = []
        start = quarter
        for line in range(quarter):
            self.secondquarter.append([])
            for col in range(self.dimention[1]):
                self.secondquarter[line].append(self.nextcellstate([line + start, col]))
                with lock:
                    if self.secondquarter[line][col] == 0:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line][col], fill='white')
                    else:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line][col], fill='green')

    def nextthirdquarterstate(self, quarter, lock):
        self.thirdquarter = []
        start = quarter * 2
        for line in range(quarter):
            self.thirdquarter.append([])
            for col in range(self.dimention[1]):
                self.thirdquarter[line].append(self.nextcellstate([line + start, col]))
                with lock:
                    if self.thirdquarter[line][col] == 0:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line + start][col], fill='white')
                    else:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[line + start][col], fill='green')

    def nextfourthquarterstate(self, quarter, lock):
        self.fourthquarter = []
        start = quarter * 3
        for line in range(quarter):
            self.fourthquarter.append([])
            for col in range(self.dimention[1]):
                self.fourthquarter[line].append(self.nextcellstate([start + line, col]))
                with lock:
                    if self.firstquarter[line][col] == 0:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[start + line][col], fill='white')
                    else:
                        self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(self.cellids[start + line][col], fill='green')

    def evolve(self):
        self.newmatrice = []
        threads = []
        lock = threading.Lock()
        quarter = int(self.dimention[0] / 4) # Division de la matrice en 4 pour reduire le temps de calcul
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.nextfirstquarterstate, args=(quarter, lock))) # Premier quart
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.nextsecondquarterstate, args=(quarter, lock))) # Deuxieme quart
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.nextthirdquarterstate, args=(quarter, lock))) # 3eme quart
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.nextfourthquarterstate, args=(quarter, lock))) # 4eme quart
        i = 0
        for t in threads:
            t.setDaemon(True)
            try:
                t.start() # Lancement des 4 threads
            except:
                print("Error: not able to lauch thread " + str(i))
            i += 1
        for t in threads:
            t.join() # Attente de la fin de tous les calculs
        self.matrice = self.firstquarter + self.secondquarter + self.thirdquarter + self.fourthquarter
    """Binding Methodes"""
    def changestateonclick(self, idcell, event):
        color = self.graphiquematrice.itemcget(idcell, 'fill')
        if color == 'white':
            self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(idcell, fill='green')
        else:
            self.graphiquematrice.itemconfig(idcell, fill='white')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainFrame()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't call `t.join()` since it will block the application until the thread task completes.

Comment: I have to wait that all the threads ends because they are updating the matrix . If i don't call `t.join()` , my matrix is empty at the next state.